# C++ 2d array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

The following line doesn't work:

```
int n1=10,v1=10;  
int f[n1][v1]={};
error: variable-sized object ‘f’ may not be initialized
```

But the line below works, why?

```
const int n1=10,v1=10;  
int f[n1][v1]={};
```

Comment: In the first, `f` is a variable-length array. Those cannot be initialised. In the second, it's not a VLA, hence can be initialised.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c for a discussion of why you are limited to fixed length arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array initializers need to be const.

An int value can change where as a const int value will remain constant throughout the entire program.

Comment: I see, Could I put const int parameters? void test1(const int& n){
  int f0[n];
  int f1[n]={};
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)cout<<f0[i]<<" "<<f1[i]<<endl;
}

Comment: It doesn't seem so, this was tested with G++ 4.5.3 under Cygwin:
http://codepaste.net/gwnck4

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, `n1` and `v1` are known to be compile-time constants. In the first example, they may not be.